# Four Dimensional Matrix

Tags: matrices, double-sequence

I have some multiple questions regarding 4D matrix. I understood that any element of a 4d matrix is itself a 2d matrix. Let $A$ and $B$ be two 4d matrices, then how to find $AB$, i.e. their product? Next is how to define identity matrix in case of 4d matrices? And last, how to find the inverse of a given 4d matrix?

Comment: What is your definition of a 4d matrix exactly? Is it just a $4\times 4$-matrix?

Comment: No @Dietrich . I suppose this notation will help you: $A=(a_{ijkl})$.

Comment: A 4D array is a list of 3D arrays which are lists of 2D arrays (2D matrices) which are just lists (vectors) of values (scalars).